# Evolution with GnuPG: "no imported public key" even if it is imported

Tags: debian, gnome, gpg, evolution, yubikey

I was running Evolution on Debian buster (testing) amd64 with GnuPG to encrypt mails. I have my GPG private key on a YubiKey actings as GPG smartcard. As Evolution somehow failed to load my calendars using CalDAV, I [resetted Evolution](https://askubuntu.com/a/243220/). CalDAV is working fine now.

But after the reset another issue appeared: GPG encrypting/signing isn't working anymore. Mails are decrypted without problems.

<strike>Furthermore, I can not choose my own GPG key in the account's settings, even if it is imported properly and gets listed in `gpg -K`:</strike>

[image]

I'm now able to choose my key.

When I try to send an encryoted mail this fails with Evolution showing the following error:

```
Could not create message.
You may need to select different mail options.
Detailed error: Failed to encrypt: Invalid recipient <my@mail.address>  specified. A common issue is that the gpg2 doesn’t have imported public key for this recipient.
```

But my public key **is** imported. The same thing happens when I disable the option `Always encrypt to myself when sending encrypted messages with this account`. The error then is:

```
Detailed error: Failed to encrypt: Invalid recipient <recipients@mail.address> specified. A common issue is that the gpg2 doesn’t have imported public key for this recipient.
```

Encrypting/signing from command line with the `gpg` command works fine. Using a private key which is not on a smartcard also did not work. Resetting both GPG and Evolution did not work.

I don't have any idea now what I should do now. Thank you all in advance :)

**EDIT**: output of `strace -p $(pidof evolution) -f -e trace=execve` when decrypting (works fine):

```
[pid  4613] execve("/usr/local/bin/gpg2", ["gpg2", "--verbose", "--no-secmem-warning", "--no-greeting", "--no-tty", "--status-fd=66", "--command-fd=67", "--verify-options", "show-photos", "--photo-viewer", "/usr/lib/evolution/camel-gpg-pho"..., "--decrypt", "--output", "-"], [/* 34 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  4613] execve("/usr/bin/gpg2", ["gpg2", "--verbose", "--no-secmem-warning", "--no-greeting", "--no-tty", "--status-fd=66", "--command-fd=67", "--verify-options", "show-photos", "--photo-viewer", "/usr/lib/evolution/camel-gpg-pho"..., "--decrypt", "--output", "-"], [/* 34 vars */]) = 0
```

When encrypting (which fails):

```
[pid  4537] execve("/usr/local/bin/gpg2", ["gpg2", "--verbose", "--no-secmem-warning", "--no-greeting", "--no-tty", "--batch", "--yes", "--status-fd=67", "--encrypt", "--armor", "-u", "my@mail.address", "-r", "<recipients@mail.address>", "--output", "-"], [/* 34 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  4537] execve("/usr/bin/gpg2", ["gpg2", "--verbose", "--no-secmem-warning", "--no-greeting", "--no-tty", "--batch", "--yes", "--status-fd=67", "--encrypt", "--armor", "-u", "my@mail.address", "-r", "<recipients@mail.address>", "--output", "-"], [/* 34 vars */]) = 0
```

The file `/usr/local/bin/gpg2` doesn't exist and seems not to be [part of any Debian package](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fgpg2).

**EDIT2**: The command @Hauke Laging posted in the comments works, but I interactively needed to confirm to execute the action (as it also was when I manually encrypted using the command line):

```
echo foo | /usr/bin/gpg2 --status-fd=1 --encrypt --armor -u my@mail.address -r recipients@mail.address --output -
```

While the command which Evolution wants to execute fails (I removed the `<>` as that causes issues with zsh):

```
➜  ~  gpg2 --verbose --no-secmem-warning --no-greeting --no-tty --batch --yes --status-fd=67 --encrypt --armor -u my@mail.address -r recipients@mail.address --output
gpg: Fatal: status-fd is invalid: Bad file descriptor
```

Setting `--status-fd=1` still fails, but with different errors:

```
➜  ~ echo "foo" | gpg2 --verbose --no-secmem-warning --no-greeting --no-tty --batch --yes --status-fd=1 --encrypt --armor -u my@mail.address -r recipients@mail.address --output -
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED <recipient's key fingerprint> 0
gpg: using pgp trust model
gpg: using subkey <recipient's encryption subkey id> instead of primary key <recipient's primary key id>
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED <recipient's key fingerprint> 0
gpg: automatically retrieved 'recipients@mail.address' via Local
gpg: <recipient's encryption subkey id>: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user
[GNUPG:] INV_RECP 10 recipients@mail.address
[GNUPG:] FAILURE encrypt 53
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: Unusable public key
```

**EDIT3:** Just tested: signing messages from Evolution works as well as decrypting.

When I manually encrypt a message using the command line, I get the following message which I think causes this issue:

```
➜  ~ echo "foo" | gpg --encrypt -r recipients@mail.address --armor
gpg: automatically retrieved 'recipients@mail.address' via Local
gpg: <recipient's encryption subkey id>: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user
sub  rsa4096/<recipient's encryption subkey id> 2015-10-14 Recipient's Name <recipients@mail.address>
 Primary key fingerprint: <recipient's key fingerprint>
      Subkey fingerprint: <recipient's encryption subkey fingerprint>

It is NOT certain that the key belongs to the person named
in the user ID.  If you *really* know what you are doing,
you may answer the next question with yes.

Use this key anyway? (y/N) y
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
[...]
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

**EDIT4**: As the message above is caused by missing ownertrust (at least I think so), I'd like to set the recipient's ownertrust using `gpg --edit-key` (which was not set before):

```
gpg> trust 
pub  rsa4096/<some key id>
     created: <some date in the past>  expires: <some date in the future>  usage: SCA 
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
sub  rsa4096/<some other key id>
     created: <some date in the past>  expires: <some date in the future>  usage: E   
[ unknown] (1). Pecipient's Name <recipients@mail.address>

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision? 3

pub  rsa4096/<some key id>
     created: <some date in the past>  expires: <some date in the future>  usage: SCA 
     trust: marginal      validity: unknown
sub  rsa4096/<some other key id>
     created: <some date in the past>  expires: <some date in the future>  usage: E   
[ unknown] (1). Pecipient's Name <recipients@mail.address>
```

So I set the recipient's ownertrust, but why is there still this `[ unknown]` at the end?

Comment: Do you have several versions of GnuPG installed (maybe without being aware)?

Comment: I'm not sure be it seems like I have only gpg2 installed: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/278ca7838d4cb05f43f0bb111df11d2e I don't think that the old gpg1 is still available on debian buster. `/usr/bin/gpg2` is also a symlink to `gpg`, so I dont think that I have several gpg versions.

Comment: Can you attach `strace -p $PID -f -e trace=execve` to Evolution? What is the exact gpg call?

Comment: See my edit above :)

Comment: `echo foo | /usr/bin/gpg2 --status-fd=1 --encrypt --armor -u my@mail.address -r recipients@mail.address --output -` works?

Comment: @HaukeLaging see my edits, I think I found out what the problem was (but not solved it)

Comment: I seriously wonder what your "Encrypting/signing from command line with the gpg command works fine." referred to...

Answer (score 3):

You haven't understood how the OpenPGP validity scheme works. But independent of that: Applications should not have a problem using non-valid keys (so you might complain towards the Evolution developers).

There are two ways (with GnuPG in standard mode) how a certificate can become valid:

1. Its ownertrust is set to ultimate.
2. It has a (valid, i.e. non-expired) signature from a valid (i.e. non-expired) signature from a key with ultimate ownertrust.

This means: If no certificate in your keyring has ultimate ownertrust then you have automatically lost.

Alternatively you can change the trust model with

```
--trust-model direct
```

Then you can set the validity directly as you tried. But in any case the certificate must be "completely valid". Marginal validity is not enough.

I have explained that in detail on my web site:

http://www.hauke-laging.de/sicherheit/openpgp.html#wot

The text is German but there are some images in that block which might be helpful for understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Enabling `Always trust keys in my keyring for encrypting` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Either that, or sign the public key of the recipient in your gpg keybox